# How to get the screenshot of a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, win32gui

I am trying to build a program which gets me an enlarged photo of the text I want, for this I decided to use **tkinter, win32gui and pygetwindow** modules after taking some tips from already asked problems on stack overflow am having the following problems:

(1)**I don't know how to get the hwnd value of the tkinter window which I created.**

(2)**I can't get hwnd value even if I know how to get it as the window is created after the complete code has run.**

So please suggest me solutions to the problem

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import win32gui
import pygetwindow as gw

#making the tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('DaysLeft')

#getting all the windows with their hwnd values
hwnd=gw.getAllWindows()
print(hwnd)

win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
bbox = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)
img.show()

mainloop()
```

The above code gives error below **as expected**:.

```
 line 26, in <module>
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
TypeError: The object is not a PyHANDLE object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PIL` for taking a screenshot and `win32gui` or `pygetwindow` to get windows location.

Install `PIL` by saying

```
pip install Pillow
```

then your working code would be:

```
from tkinter import *
from win32gui import FindWindow, GetWindowRect
import pygetwindow as gw
from PIL import ImageGrab

def ss():
    win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('DaysLeft')[0]
    winleft = win.left+9
    wintop = win.top+38 #change 38 to 7 to not capture the titlebar
    winright = win.right-9
    winbottom = win.bottom-9
    final_rect = (winleft,wintop,winright,winbottom)
    img = ImageGrab.grab(final_rect)
    img.save('Required Image.png')
#making the tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('DaysLeft')

root.after(3000,ss)

root.mainloop()
```

Why am i subtracting some amount from the pixels? its because, windows has decorations like drop shadow effect to the windows, which are also part of the windows and will be included in the screenshot, so i used this to get rid of those extra pixels.

Or if your still reluctant on using `win32gui` then, change the function to:

```
from win32gui import FindWindow, GetWindowRect
from PIL import ImageGrab
......
def ss():
    win = FindWindow(None, 'DaysLeft')
    rect = GetWindowRect(win)
    list_rect = list(rect)
    list_frame = [-9, -38, 9, 9] #change -38 to -7 to not capture the titlebar
    final_rect = tuple((map(lambda x,y:x-y,list_rect,list_frame))) #subtracting two lists

    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=final_rect)
    img.save('Image.png')
```

What is `after` method? It just calls the function after 3000 ms, i.e, 3 seconds.  We are basically giving the system some time to build the GUI and capture screenshot.

Hope it helped, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer, I tried the second method first and found the following error that you have named list1 and list2 while subtracting and used list_frame and list_rect while assigning. Please check if it was a mistake or was intentional.

Comment: I am getting the following error:

 " line 25, in <module>
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(win)
pywintypes.error: (1400, 'GetWindowRect', 'Invalid window handle.')
"

Comment: I tried your first method but as I think since the window has not yet become active therefore it gives the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SAMSUNG/PycharmProjects/daysleftproject/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('window')[0]






IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @RudraanshPatel Ive updated the code and fixed the errors, such that itll work for your code